# Where can I download the U.S. NEC at no cost?

Tags: nec

Is there a website where I can access the ***complete*** and most recently updated version of the United States NEC for ***free***?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the NEC. Is free once adopted . search for free NEC and you will find it. This is only for the "code" I don't think they release the hand book that has a lot of information on why, this is the version most inspectors use , but once adopted the NEC is free on line. Just checked look up nfpa.org free access just need to sign in..

[Free Access to NEC](https://www.nfpa.org/codes-and-standards/all-codes-and-standards/list-of-codes-and-standards/detail?code=70)

Comment: It is free to observe it on the web, but it will not allow you to copy text, print the pages or export them.

Answer (score 2):

The City of Tool, TX, USA, has provided a freely downloadable and fully searchable [PDF of the NEC 2017](https://www.tooltexas.org/departments/building-code) (approx. 7MB), currently (April 2020) [in effect in most US states](https://www.nfpa.org/nec/nec-adoption-and-use/nec-adoption-maps), to be accessed *without* the need to create an account. I assume they have a license.